# about the use of "case of" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I think `case of` is quite straight forward, as i come from more imperative languages.
Nevertheless, i have encountered a Kata where one of the solutions by another user, confuses me about the use of case and `Data.List (sort)`

```
import Data.List (sort)

isTriangle :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
isTriangle a b c =
  case sort [a,b,c] of
     [min, middle, max] -> (min + middle) > max
```

By definition, 3 segments can make a triangle if the condition `a + b > c` is met for the 3 permutations of [a,b,c] so, something more straight forward (my answer) would be:

```
isTriangle :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
isTriangle a b c = a + b > c && b + c > a && a + c > b
```

My question is, in the case above, how is the `case of` testing that condition for the 3 combinations?

Comment: Mathematically, if you know `(min + middle) > max`, then you know that the other permutations also hold true. Just think about what will happen to the left hand side of the equation if you replace min or middle with max, will it be higher or lower? And what happens to the right hand side when you put the variable you replaced from the left hand side there?

Comment: that makes sense, but then why are we using `case of`?

Comment: That said... Here, `case... of...` is used in an unusual way where it only has one matching pattern which will always be hit. For cases like this, `let ... in ...` or `... where ...` is more commonly used

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez: to sort the list of three items, and thus work with the smallest, medium and largest element.

Comment: i think i get it. @ShamPooSham can you put that in form of an answer, so i can upvote and mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: I agree with @ShamPooSham, this would be slightly better expressed (imo) as `isTriangle a b c = let [min, middle, max] = sort [a, b, c] in (min + middle) > max`

Comment: @RobinZigmond: well it's a bit sad that there is no sort variant for 2-, 3-, etc. tuples, since that guarantees at type level that the number of items remains the same. While this is of course the case, it is usually better if the type system can guarantee this :s.

Comment: the use of `case...of` is better than the alternatives since its purpose here is the pattern-matching destructuring of the return value of the sort call, and "`case...of`" is literally saying "pattern match!" while `let` (and `where`) are only implying it; secondly, the execution direction with `case` is all in one direction as reading the code, left-to-right, unlike with the other two. `let` and `where` go better with the lazy bindings, but here we actually want strictness i.e. reading the code as being a recipe for _execution_, not as a lazy _definition_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that a b and c are ordered from small to large, then the algorithm tests that *a + b > c*, which is what the first implementation checks.

If we know that *a < b < c*, and *a + b > c* holds, then we know that *a + c > b* holds. Indeed: *a + c > a + b > c > b*, hence *a + c > b* holds because *a + b > c* holds. Furthermore *b + c > a + b > c > a* holds, and thus *b + c > a* holds as well.

This thus means that checking if it holds for a known minimum, maximum and value in between, the two other equations are implied.

What the `case … of` does here is sorting the list `[a, b, c]` and unpacking the sorted list in `min`, `middle` and `max`, it is thus a tool that is used to assign the smallest value to `min`, the largest value to `max` and the remaining value to `middle`. A `where …` or `let … in …` is probably more elegant, for example:

```
isTriangle :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
isTriangle a b c = (min + middle) > max
  where [min, middle, max] = sort [a, b, c]
```

Comment: yeah,  it was the esoteric use of `case of` that confused me, but it's good to know